# Cursor location accessing methods

Tags: python, scripting

Can you provide me with different methods, or at least one, for accessing the vector of cursor location?
I need anything but the one described in this line of code:

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
```

I do not want to access any method in my code using "context"! My code reloads the modules recursively and Blender for no reason I know always loses context when I do so. By the way, lots of people are complaining about losing context in scripts and add-ons after reloading Blender (not in a direct way). If you have any suggestions I would be more than glad.

Comment: Suggest if you don't know something ask a question. If it involves code, show code. Try and avoid "hearsay" in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .blend file [can contain many scenes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/data_system/scenes/introduction.html). Each `scene` has a `.cursor_location` attribute:

```
>>> {scene.name:scene.cursor_location for scene in bpy.data.scenes}
{'Scene': Vector((0.9819498062133789, -5.541140079498291, -6.299274444580078))}
```

If you know the name of the scene, (e.g. `'Scene'`), you could use

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].cursor_location
```

Comment: Thx that worked just fine.